# Spinner is not defined in Ladda with RequireJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs, spin.js

I am trying to place a ladda button on page rendered by backbone with require.js along with bootstrap components.  However, I got

> `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined".`

I cut out the minified spin.js from the original ladda.js and put them in the same directory.

Shim'ed ladda as below:

```
require.config ({
   paths: {
            //jquery, underscore, backbone here
            spin : 'libs/ladda/spin',
            ladda: 'libs/ladda/ladda'
   },

   shim: {
        ladda: {
            deps: ['spin'],
            exports: 'Ladda'    
    }
}
});
```

In backbone view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'bootstrap',
  'spin',
  'ladda',
 ], function($, _, Backbone, Bootstrap, Spinner, ladda){
    render: function () {
        //templating

        console.log ('Spinner: ' + typeof Spinner);
        Ladda.create ($('button'));    
   }
});
```

I could see `typeof Spinner` is a function.  Spinner.name property is "p".  Shouldn't Spinner.name be "Spinner" instead of "p"?  or "p" is inherit from minified variable?

What other steps I miss out to make Spinner visible in scope to ladda.js?  Appreciate any advice render.

Thank you.

**Update:**
Thanks to Bass Jobsen's advice, use hakimel committed `spin.js`, `Spinner` is loaded but error still persist.  Below Chrome Dev Tool console:

[image: chrome devtool screenshot]

Comment: ladda.js calls var spinner = new Spinner; so spinner should be a object? When i rewrite spinner to window.Spinner =(function() {
  "use strict"; ...... (skipp the first wrapper). spinner still be a object but the error will be ` spinner.spin is not a function`. Note i use define in stead of require, see also; http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/re-learning-backbone-js-require-js-and-amd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on github.com/hakimel/Ladda/pull/7 i rewrote spin.js to a class like Ladda itself. I used define instead require (http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/re-learning-backbone-js-require-js-and-amd/).
Now spinner is a object too.

`Ladda.bind()` doesn't seems to work (or i don't understand what to expect). You could create a new button object: `Ladda.create()`;

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/DuIVFP0UP8sSoek9gEZc

```
//https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn   
requirejs.config({
    //"baseUrl": "js/lib",
    enforceDefine: true,
    "paths": {
      "app": "app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",
      "spin": "spin",
      "ladda": "ladda"
    },
    shim: {
        "spin": {exports: "Spinner"},
        "ladda": {
            depends: "spin",
            exports: "Ladda"
        },



        }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**app/main.js**:

```
define(["jquery",'ladda','spin'], function($,ladda) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
      console.log("$: " + typeof $);
      console.log("ladda: " + typeof Ladda);
      console.log("spin: " + typeof Spinner);

      Ladda.bind($('button')[0]); //don't work ????????????
      //return;
      //Ladda.create('.ladda-button');
      var l = Ladda.create($('button')[1]);

    l.start();

// Will display a progress bar for 50% of the button width
l.setProgress( 5 );

// Stop loading
l.stop();

// Toggle between loading/not loading states
l.toggle();

// Check the current state
l.isLoading();


    });
});
```

Comment: This works!  Excellent workaround by removing AMD module and planted `window.Spinner`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be with `ladda` with lowercase `l`. Cause this is the name of the argument in your require function.

```
ladda.create ($('button'));
```

Comment: changed to ladda (with lowercase l), with and without RequireJS `exports`, error persists.